# Ethereum raw transaction structure

Tags: transactions, ethereumjs, chaindata

I'm trying to learn the raw transaction data structure for Ethereum. Here my transaction (ropsten network) :

> 0xf8691285012a05f2008307a12094b75fe87f44cb2003f3472424261f021d2100ce5a80843ccfd60b2aa0fce2a70cde55dc86a203d2387469c36da00e9a9f3536b867f6761c314b1f1423a07b85742fd48a687b8daa097d1fb9d4b5135de6deb5b6fd16dd0f28d6c28727b6

**0x**

**f869** ???

**12** (nonce)

**850** ???

**12a05f200** (gasprice)

**830** ???

**7a120** (gas limit)

**94** ???

**b75fe87f44cb2003f3472424261f021d2100ce5a** (to)

**8084** ???

**3ccfd60b** (data because smart contract interaction)

**2a** (v + chainId*2)

**a0** (160 in hex)

**fce2a70cde55dc86a203d2387469c36da00e9a9f3536b867f6761c314b1f1423** (r)

**a0** (160 in hex)

**7b85742fd48a687b8daa097d1fb9d4b5135de6deb5b6fd16dd0f28d6c28727b6** (s)

What are other line ? Like "f869" , "850" after nonce, "830" after gasPrice, "94" before TO ans "8084" after to?

Answer (score 1):

```
0x
//  https://eth.wiki/fundamentals/rlp for more on f8
// 0xf8-0xf7=1byte=2 chars which tells you next 2 chars is the length of the paylaod
f8
// length of payload. 0x69=105bytes=210 chars. 
69
// Nonce. 1byte
12 
//0x85-0x80=133-128= 5bytes=10chars= GAS PRICE
85 012a05f200
// 0x83-0x80=131-128=3bytes=6chars= GAS LIMIT
83 07a120
// 0x94 - 0x80=148-128=20bytes=40chars= TO
94 b75fe87f44cb2003f3472424261f021d2100ce5a
// this should be value. empty valu, string is represended as 80
80 
// 0x84-0x80=132-128=4bytes=8 chars= DATA
84 3ccfd60b
// "v" value. 1byte
2a
// a0-0x80=160-128=32 bytes=64 chars= "r" VALUE
a0 fce2a70cde55dc86a203d2387469c36da00e9a9f3536b867f6761c314b1f1423
// a0-0x80=160-128=32 bytes=64 chars= "s" VALUE
a0 7b85742fd48a687b8daa097d1fb9d4b5135de6deb5b6fd16dd0f28d6c28727b6
```